# How to run multiple CountDown Timer at the same time that run separately?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a quiz android app in which what I'm trying to implement is to show count down until the quiz starts to the user and when the countdown counts to zero, the start button is activated.

Initially there is one quiz with a countdown of 60 seconds (i.e. after 60 seconds the start button for the quiz should be activated). **Now the problem I'm facing is that when I add a new quiz in the listview, with the countdown limit of 30 seconds, the countdown of this new quiz stops after 30 seconds but the countdown of first quiz is also displayed in the second quiz's start button**

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        // Check if the existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        View listItemView = convertView;
        if(listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.upcoming_quiz, parent, false);
        }

        // Get the {@link QuizCard} object located at this position in the list
        QuizCard quizCard = getItem(position);

        // Find the start quiz button
        final Button start_quiz_btn = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.start_quiz_btn);
        // Set countDownTimer
        CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(quizCard.getCountDownTime(), 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                start_quiz_btn.setText(Long.toString(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // Set the button clickable
                start_quiz_btn.setClickable(true);
                // Set the button enabled
                start_quiz_btn.setEnabled(true);

                // Change the text of the button
                start_quiz_btn.setText(R.string.start_quiz);
            }
        };

        // Start the count down timer
        countDownTimer.start();

        return listItemView;
    }
```

In my code, what I'm doing is I've created a custom listview adpater in which I pass the count down limit to when to start the quiz.

Comment: you can have as many `CountDownTimer`s running as you want - they work independently

Comment: Can you put some code which would help us to understand the problem better?

Comment: @pskink Yes, like for two quizes i'm creating two countdown timers, but they both somehow are getting terminated at same time

Comment: @NatigBabayev I have putted the code of the listview adapter where i'm implementing the countdown timer on the start button. Here for two quizzes, two start button will be showed on the screen where countdown should be going on.

Comment: @Jorvis in sample code there's only one countdownTimer.

Comment: @NatigBabayev This code is a snippet of my listview adapter, when two items will be there in the list, two countdown timers will be there

Comment: getView is called whenever new item is added to the list. In my case when i press add quiz a new quiz is added to the list. So my problem is when new quiz is added, the timer stops as soon as the timer for first quiz stops

Comment: There's not enough info here in order to understand your issue. My guess is that the countdowntimers share a global/static variable, but it's just a guess